# how to set several conditions on textAreaInput in shiny

Tags: r, input, shiny

My shiny works well. But I need some new conditions on textAreaInput().

**My queston is:**

**Firstly,** I mean I hope the upper genes input limit is 5 each time.

**Secondly,** if the input number is more than 5 and some input genes of them not match my total gene data, I hope it can be delete automatically.

**Also,** if the input number is more than 5 and all of them match my gene data, I hope only 5 input genes are selected and others should be removed.

I have add  `tolower()` and `capitalize()`and `unique()` to initialize the input gene to let all of the input genes and my total gene data be the same standard.

#### Here is my code, it works well:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)
library(pheatmap)
library(Hmisc)      ##  upper and lower

data<-structure(list(Name = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
                          "C", "D"), `0610005C13Rik` = c(0.424665254943466, 0.279103397038561, 
                                                         0.158078889243373, 0.1439331633966, 0.226678169539756, 0.123022674203591, 
                                                         0, 0.0575264589421532, 0.0941181834571747, 0.271984789609661), 
                 `0610006L08Rik` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `0610007P14Rik` = c(12.806118142651, 
                                                                                        11.4382552893482, 13.9357832217265, 14.2645292042994, 14.945765717404, 
                                                                                        14.5469997037148, 6.60925104569544, 8.5208866040503, 7.67759477655631, 
                                                                                        5.1250399195198), `0610009B22Rik` = c(7.52603796214715, 6.55433995648707, 
                                                                                                                              7.32295752983399, 7.11970579975653, 6.33099006794741, 7.12373599276529, 
                                                                                                                              5.86943489378519, 3.56825071218655, 3.9535564719271, 3.48802886940983
                                                                                        ), `0610009E02Rik` = c(0.185168046030845, 0.247821949927601, 
                                                                                                               0.231596753511727, 0.175726887193673, 0.276749625923402, 
                                                                                                               0.300394864975905, 0.263269726601418, 0.140467218570394, 
                                                                                                               0.114908163045647, 0.110688042779122), `0610009L18Rik` = c(1.31956911898427, 
                                                                                                                                                                          1.60969164366343, 1.26074937062469, 0.78268017446358, 1.11523776096204, 
                                                                                                                                                                          0.947711828658839, 3.45263289541606, 1.35554269811025, 0.938292908100525, 
                                                                                                                                                                          1.31466638208741), `0610009O20Rik` = c(18.7299635259571, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 17.3842871293536, 18.5627752307553, 21.4629852251455, 22.6402836654957, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 21.2444396709145, 20.8497978564997, 21.8549813492263, 17.9002684065608, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 23.4418304775222), `0610010B08Rik` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0, 0, 0, 0), `0610010F05Rik` = c(5.1366066315153, 4.4875410833769, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         4.68456790443224, 4.63427490124717, 4.49675344401973, 4.14533562229927, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         1.73688504460735, 2.29599806910547, 2.02824204009348, 2.27745145230829
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ), `0610010K14Rik` = c(34.965811473297, 28.7179970696566, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               32.5977715269141, 29.9814513489617, 29.9262002003054, 30.0479176240035, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               38.071647586648, 29.7626650589632, 28.6266691732093, 27.7424485401854
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        )), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")##


##


##
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    mainPanel("123",
      width = 9,
                  tabPanel("666",
                           hr(),
                           textAreaInput("n", 
                                         width = 380,
                                         "555", 
                                         rows = 4,
                                         cols = 1),
                           
                           actionButton("submit", "Submit",width=120),
                           hr(),
                           uiOutput("all")

                           
                  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(list(input$submit), {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "123",
                      selected = "666"
    )
  })

  
  
  
  ###########################
  global <- reactiveValues(out = NULL
  )

  output$all <- renderUI({          
    global$out
  })

  observeEvent(input$submit,{
    
    global$out <- plotOutput("myPlot_enrichment")

  })
  
  #########################################
  myPlot_enrichment = reactiveVal()
  # ################################################################# enrichment
  observeEvent(input$submit, {

    names(data)<-names(data)%>%tolower()%>%capitalize()
    genes=as.vector(unlist(strsplit(input$n,"[ \n]")))
    genes<-genes%>%tolower()%>%capitalize()%>%unique()
    genes<-intersect(genes,names(data))
    validate(
      need(sum(unique(colnames(data[,-1])) %in% genes)<=5, "The number of genes is out of range."))
    
    data_new<-t(data[,genes])
    ##############
    myPlot_enrichment(
      if(nrow(data_new)>1){
        pheatmap(log2(data_new+1), show_colnames = F,fontsize_row =8,
                 labels_row = as.expression(lapply(rownames(data_new), function(a) bquote(italic(.(a))))),
                 cluster_rows = T, cluster_cols = F,
                 fontsize = 11,
                 cellwidth=4
        )
      }
    )
  }) 

  ##################################  enrichment
  output$myPlot_enrichment = renderPlot({
    req(myPlot_enrichment())
    myPlot_enrichment()
  })
}
# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I hope somebody give me some advice.

##### update: 2022年02.10.14:45:49

I have solve my problem partly but I meet a problem again:
here is my new code:

```
myPlot_enrichment(
      if(0<length(genes)<6) {
        data_new<-t(data[,genes])
        pheatmap(log2(data_new+1), show_colnames = F,fontsize_row =8,
                 labels_row = as.expression(lapply(rownames(data_new), function(a) bquote(italic(.(a))))),
                 cluster_rows = T, cluster_cols = F,
                 fontsize = 11,
                 cellwidth=4
        )
      }else{
        data_new<-t(data[,genes[1:5]])
        pheatmap(log2(data_new+1), show_colnames = F,fontsize_row =8,
                 labels_row = as.expression(lapply(rownames(data_new), function(a) bquote(italic(.(a))))),
                 cluster_rows = T, cluster_cols = F,
                 fontsize = 11,
                 cellwidth=4
        )
        
      }
    )
```

It works well if I just run the `if else` module out of the `myPlot_enrichment()`. However, it doesn't work if I run the `if else` module in the `myPlot_enrichment()`.

I don't know why. I hope somebody could give me some advice.

**The error message below:**

```
Error in nchar(sm[1L], type = "w") : invalid multibyte string, element 1
```

Comment: @YBS sir, my last question. I still need your help.

Comment: @YBS  where are you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I find there always exist bug in R or shiny.

But I tried my best and find the perfect way to solve my problem.

**Here is my new code:
it works well.**

```
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    names(data)<-names(data)%>%tolower()%>%capitalize()
    genes=as.vector(unlist(strsplit(input$n,"[ \n]")))
    genes<-genes%>%tolower()%>%capitalize()%>%unique()
    genes<-intersect(genes,names(data))
    validate(
      need(sum(unique(colnames(data_FPKM2[,-1])) %in% genes)>0, "The number of genes is out of range."))
    data_new<-t(data[,genes])
    data_new=round(data_new, 2)
    ##############
    myPlot_enrichment(
      
      if(length(genes)<6){
        data_new<-t(data[,genes])
        pheatmap(log2(data_new+1), show_colnames = F,fontsize_row =8,
                 labels_row = as.expression(lapply(rownames(data_new), function(a) bquote(italic(.(a))))),
                 cluster_rows = T, cluster_cols = F,
                 fontsize = 11,
                 cellwidth=4
        )
      } else if(length(genes)>5){
        data_new<-t(data_FPKM2[,genes[1:5]])
        pheatmap(log2(data_new+1), show_colnames = F,fontsize_row =8,
                 labels_row = as.expression(lapply(rownames(data_new), function(a) bquote(italic(.(a))))),
                 cluster_rows = T, cluster_cols = F,
                 fontsize = 11,
                 cellwidth=4
        )
      }
    )
  })
```